# how can i avoid asking username and password for facebook in my UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, ios-4.2

in my app i need a facebook like button. when user will click that button it ll like a facebook group. i used a UIWebView and used iframe in that. now i have a local html document which is loaded when user click on the webView. but when i click on the webView it asks for facebook user name and password. i also have a publish button which uses facebook api. once its loged in it doesn't ask username and password again. but webView asks always. how can i get auto login in webView?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=37430

Comment: didn't help. still asking for username and password